# pinning dependency version to folder with sbt/ivy

Tags: scala, sbt, ivy

Our project consists of multiple subprojects which we publish in a local Nexus. Now, when working on a library, we would like to use this library and build the application without having to upload this library to Nexus all the time.

For a prototypical example, consider we have two projects A and B, with B depending on A:

A/build.sbt:

```
version := 0.1.7
organization := "org.example"
name := "libraryA"
scalaVersion := "2.11.8"
libraryDependencies += "some.external" % "dependency" % "0.1"
```

B/build.sbt:

```
version := 0.2.3
organization := "org.example"
name := "applicationB"
scalaVersion := "2.11.8"
libraryDependencies += "some.other.external" % "dependency" % "0.2"
libraryDependencies += "org.example" % "libraryA" % "0.1.7"
```

Now let's say I want to work on libraryA and want to test my changes by running applicationB. So I check out A and B to some local folders respectively. Our current approaches are the following:

- increment the version number in `A/build.sbt` and the dependency in `B/build.sbt`. Then do

  ```
  (cd A && sbt publishLocal) && (cd B && sbt compile)
  ```

  The version incrementation may not be necessary when using a -SNAPSHOT version (but I'm not sure about this); in any case we always need to do the publishLocal call.
- add a new `build.sbt` that contain both projects A and B:

  ```
  lazy val A = (project in file("A")).settings(
    version := 0.1.7-SNAPSHOT,
    organization := "org.example",
    name := "libraryA",
    scalaVersion := "2.11.8",
    libraryDependencies += "some.external" % "dependency" % "0.1"
  )

  lazy val B = (project in file("B")).settings(
    version := "0.2.3",
    organization := "org.example"
    name := "applicationB"
    scalaVersion := "2.11.8"
    libraryDependencies += "some.other.external" % "dependency" % "0.2"
  ).dependsOn(A)
  ```

  This has the disadvantage that for every combination of applications/libraries we want to currently hack on, we have to create a new `build.sbt` file and also this has a lot of duplications from the other build.sbt files.

  But it has the advantage that to compile the application with the modified library, we now only have to write `sbt B/compile`.

What we ideally want to have is some way to *pin* specific library versions to specific folders. This should fix a dependency in the transitive graph to the specific version, and it should be possible for this to be a folder that gets compiled then. The process should look like the following:

- check out A and B
- in folder B, do `sbt pin "org.example%libraryA%0.1.7" folder/A`
- then, every time we want to compile application B with the current library version, just do `sbt compile`.

Is there something like this available in sbt? I've been told by my coworker that ocaml has something like this (it's called `opam pin` there).

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you can provide versions to your dependencies in [Ivy dynamic version format](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/ivyfile/dependency.html). For example, "1.2.+" or "latest.integration".

To stick to a specific version of dependency you could use [sbt-lock plugin](https://github.com/tkawachi/sbt-lock). This plugin allows you to 'lock' dynamic version not in *build.sbt* file but in additional *lock.sbt* file. It is good idea to put this file under version control. Using plugin's commands 'unlock' and 'relock' you can change locked versions later.

Comment: thanks, but is it also possible to provide a folder with local changes instead of a version? Like is done with `dependsOn`?

Comment: May be just add "projectA/src/main" folder as sourcesDirectory in B's build.sbt? Or add compiled jar as an unmanagedJars in B?

Comment: Hm, if I understand you correctly, this wouldn't include `A/build.sbt` at all; so if I have a more complicated `build.sbt`, I'd have to duplicate it with `B.sbt`. That doesn't sound like the right solution. compiled jar might work, but then we'd still have to always do `cd A && sbt compile` before `sbt compile` in `B`, so I don't really see the benefit of this to the first approach (i.e. using `publishLocal`) with a snapshot release. Still, it's a lot of changing of build.sbt files. Ideally, I'd like to just use some command/envvar/different file(like with `lock.sbt`)to compile a local project

Comment: Yes, you right. As far as I understand, there is no way to call another sbt file from inside of your current build.sbt. And I also dislike this because I used it quite often in Ant.

Comment: But I think `ProjectRef` is exactly the feature of loading a different .sbt file and we now use the semi-automatic commenting out a `buildDependencies += xxx` line and replacing it with a `dependsOn(ProjectRef(file, target))` line. This more or less works for us now.